# how define numerical constants for using in pdf content stream?

Tags: pdf

in content stream sequeance of re commands like :

100 120 10 10 re f 
130 120 10 10 re f

how define name /a like 
<</a 10>> so 
  and where it place?  so i can possible use it like:

100 120 /a/a re f 130 120 /a/a re f

in content stream of pdf?

i try add /a 10 in /Resource object that page but nothing happen

Comment: You cannot. There only are certain kinds of resources, in particular no numerical ones.

Comment: There is no (or little) need to do this, because the compression (e.g FlateDecode) applied to the content stream will have the same effect. You are in effect trying to manually pre-compress the data. There is no need.